# Python: Keep n last columns of pandas.multiindex with respect to column index level 1

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a `pd.DataFrame` with two levels of columns. I need to keep the last `n` columns of `level 1` and delete all previous columns. The number of columns is not necessarily equal across all columns of `level 0`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=1, high=5, size=(4,12)))
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2,3],['A','B', 'C', 'D']])
df.drop((2, 'A'), axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.drop((3, 'A'), axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.drop((3, 'C'), axis = 1, inplace = True)

   1           2        3   
   A  B  C  D  B  C  D  B  D
0  3  1  4  3  4  2  4  4  4
1  4  1  4  1  1  2  4  1  1
2  3  4  3  2  3  4  3  3  1
3  2  4  4  1  4  1  1  2  3
```

Expected result:

```
   1     2     3   
   C  D  C  D  B  D
0  4  3  2  4  4  4
1  4  1  2  4  1  1
2  3  2  4  3  3  1
3  4  1  1  1  2  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with `ascending=False` for counter from back for first level of `MultiIndex` and filter last 2 columns in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), also `cumcount` failed with levels in columns, so added [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html):

```
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.to_frame().groupby(level=0).cumcount(ascending=False) < 2]
print (df)
   1     2     3   
   C  D  C  D  B  D
0  4  4  2  1  3  3
1  1  1  2  1  4  2
2  1  1  2  3  4  2
3  4  3  1  3  4  4
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.columns.to_frame().groupby(level=0).cumcount(ascending=False))
1  A    3
   B    2
   C    1
   D    0
2  B    2
   C    1
   D    0
3  B    1
   D    0
dtype: int64

print (df.columns.to_frame().groupby(level=0).cumcount(ascending=False) < 2)
1  A    False
   B    False
   C     True
   D     True
2  B    False
   C     True
   D     True
3  B     True
   D     True
dtype: bool
```

Another idea with filter last columns and then filter by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(df.columns.to_frame().groupby(level=0).tail(2).index)]
print (df)
   1     2     3   
   C  D  C  D  B  D
0  3  1  3  2  1  1
1  3  2  4  2  3  1
2  2  4  3  3  1  3
3  1  3  4  1  3  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the columns to keep only the columns you need :

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in df.columns:
    d[k].append((k, v))

#assumption is you need the last two columns, so negative indexing :
columns = list(chain.from_iterable(value[-2:] for key, value in d.items()))

df.loc[:, columns]

        1       2       3
    C   D   C   D   B   D
0   4   3   2   4   4   4
1   4   1   2   4   1   1
2   3   2   4   3   3   1
3   4   1   1   1   2   3
```